# Instrumental Testing a view on MVP

Tags: android, mocking, mvp, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm developing an Android App with an MVP architecture, I've been able to test both Presenter and Model classes, but now I'm trying to test the View methods.
For instance, I have the following view:

```
public interface SplashView extends BaseMVPView {

    void initPresenter();

    void navigateToHome();

    void onError(ApiError apiError);
}
```

Which is implemented by an Activity.

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity implements SplashView {

    // MVP Presenter
    private SplashPresenter splashPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initPresenter();
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.activity_splash;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        if(splashPresenter != null) {
            splashPresenter.onDestroy();
            splashPresenter = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initPresenter() {
        if(splashPresenter == null) {
            splashPresenter = new SplashPresenterImpl(this, ApiClient.getService());
            sync();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void navigateToHome() {
        NavigationUtils.navigateToActivity(this, MainActivity.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ApiError apiError) {
        DialogUtils.showOKCancelDialog(...);
    }

    private void sync() {
        if(splashPresenter != null) {
            splashPresenter.sync();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the activity is created it initialized the presenter and calls a method that will get some data from the API. Once the API call is done, the presenter will call either the navigateToHome or the onError methods. So I would like to test this process for both cases. I guess this must be an instrumental test but I don't know how to deal with this cases, and how to call the methods.

Thanks a lot

Comment: View shouldn't call any managing methods on presenter, like yours `sync()`, because presenter manage view, not vice versa. View should just pass to presenter its actions like click or lifecycle events if needed. Make sync method private and call it inside presenter, in your case - in constructor, but i also suggest to not create presenter manually, use factory or di like dagger and use method named `bindVIew(View view)` to connect view to presenter.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm calling the presenter's sync method from the view because it must be executed on the initialization. I thought that it was a better if the view executed that method instead of the presenter as well as it would have done with a click event. Do you think that this is better to remove that part from the view? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, i think so. Click event is an event, but sync method is not as i wrote previously. So encapsulate calling `sync` in presenter

Comment: Thank you, I'll change it as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I suggest to mix up your **MVP** architecture with some **Dagger** taste for dependency injection which really helps with testing and **Mocking**. You can learn more using the sample I have published on my Github which also contains different type of tests:

> http://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers

By the way, in this type of development you have to Mock your **SplashPresenter** and insert it instead of the real one to let you change the real presenter with a mocked presenter that do what you want.

For doing this you have to extend your Activity and override **initPresenter** method:

```
class MockSplashActivity extends SplashActivity {
    @Override
    public void initPresenter() {
        if (splashPresenter == null) {
            splashPresenter = new MockSplashPresenterImpl(this, ApiClient.getService());
            sync();
        }
    }
}
```

and also extend your presenter and change the method you want to act the way you want in testing (I think you want to do something with sync method):

```
class MockSplashPresenterImpl extends SplashPresenterImpl {
    public MockSplashPresenterImpl(SplashActivity splashActivity, Object service) {
        super(splashActivity, service);
    }

    @Override
    public void sync() {
        splashActivity.doSomethingYouWant();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll take a look at your github project. One question, why would Dragger2 help me with testing? I'm facing some problems with Dragger2, I guess I would use it in order to inject the Presenter to the View and the View to the Presenter, wouldn't I? So, what is the effect that that would have on testing? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe if you take a look at sample repo you would get the point ;)

Comment: You can also take a look at this article: https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-testing-using-dagger-2-mockito-and-a-custom-junit-rule-c8487ed01b56#.nlmlosmi3

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look!

Comment: Thank you so much! This cleared many of my doubts as I was facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mockito framework for this. Mockito.verify does what you want - it checks if specific method was called.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-and-dependency-injection-with-model-view-presenter-on-android--cms-26164
Here's article, I hope it will help.

Comment: His issue not in that how to verify calling methods, he wants to know how to mock presenter and inject such mocked instance to a fragment or activity.